# Find the schema which has the maximum increase in its object numbers in 1 year

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

In oracle,I need to  Find the schema which has the maximum increase in its object numbers in 1 year in a weekly basis by using use analytical functions

I have done something like this:

```
 SELECT OWNER, TRUNC(CREATED,'w') WEEK_OF, count(*)
 FROM dba_objects
 WHERE CREATED BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
 group by TRUNC(CREATED,'w'),OWNER
 ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Can you guys think of a way in which I can use LAG function ?

Comment: Not possible, because Oracle doesn't store the "history" of objects. So you can't retrieve the number of objects from the past.

Comment: there is a created field in dba_objects table

Comment: And how do you detect dropped tables?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually that is not my concern. I just wish to see the schema with most increased size. Drop does not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the meaning of 'object' - tables, triggers, views, anything specific? Anyway, there is a pseudotable **dba_objects** which have column CREATED for every object in DB:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_objects
```

---

So, i guess the simplest way is just this:

```
SELECT OWNER, COUNT(1) FROM dba_objects WHERE CREATED BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12) AND SYSDATE
GROUP BY OWNER
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: I meant all the object types by saying object. Not specifically table etc.

Comment: @Ege Well, then the query above should do the trick - it'll give you the number of any objects, created within the last year, for each schema.

Comment: Thank you for interesting:) What you are doing is correct actually but I'm trying to find something like let's say one user created 40 tables in one week but didn't create any other since.. and others created like 1 in each week... According to what you have done, they may seem equal in the en of the year but I'm trying to find that 40 value

Comment: Maybe this query will fit your needs:<br>  select owner, to_char( created, 'WW' ) week_number, count(*) objects_per_week
  from all_objects
  where created between to_date( '2013', 'yyyy' ) and to_date( '2014', 'yyyy' )
  group by owner, to_char( created, 'WW' )
  order by objects_per_week desc